# How do I prevent autocorrection to change part of my email address

Tags: safari, macos, auto-complete

I recently have found that when I put my email address in a safari form or other Application, it changes my name from one word to two. e.g. fredsmith@....   auto inserts to fred smith@...   Is there any way I can change this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add "fredsmith" to the OS X dictionary by right-clicking or Ctrl-clicking on it when underlined in red and selecting "Add to Dictionary".